# Still another fact about polynomials

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Let
\begin{equation}
P_{ij}^{k}(X_1,X_2,...,X_{2n-1},X_{2n})=\left\{
                                            \begin{array}{ll}
                                              X_{2j-1}, & \hbox{ if $k=2i-1$;} \\
                                              X_{2j}, & \hbox{ if $k=2i$;}\\
                                              X_{2i-1}, & \hbox{ if $k=2j-1$;} \\
                                              X_{2i}, & \hbox{ if $k=2j$;}\\
                                              0. & \hbox{ otherwise.}
                                            \end{array}
                                          \right.
\end{equation}I wonder if the following is true: If $\{Q_{i,j}\}_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}$ are polynomials
in $X_1$, $X_2$,..., $X_{2n-1}$, $X_{2n}$ such that
$$\tag{1}
\sum_{1\leq i\leq j\leq n}Q_{i,j}P_{ij}^k=0\mbox{ for all }1\leq k\leq 2n,
$$
then we must $Q_{i,j}=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq j\leq n$. I need this property to solve a system of linear first order PDEs, which is posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258222/solving-a-system-of-equations-involving-smooth-functions).

If we let $Q_{i,j}=Q_{j,i}$, then $(1)$ can be written as 
$$\tag{2}Q_{1,1}X_1+Q_{1,2}X_3+\cdots+Q_{1,n}X_{2n-1}=0,\\
Q_{1,1}X_2+Q_{1,2}X_4+\cdots+Q_{1,n}X_{2n}=0,\\
Q_{2,1}X_1+Q_{2,2}X_3+\cdots+Q_{2,n}X_{2n-1}=0,\\
Q_{2,1}X_2+Q_{2,2}X_4+\cdots+Q_{2,n}X_{2n}=0,\\
\vdots\\
Q_{n,1}X_1+Q_{n,2}X_3+\cdots+Q_{n,n}X_{2n-1}=0,\\
Q_{n,1}X_2+Q_{n,2}X_4+\cdots+Q_{n,n}X_{2n}=0.$$

Here are some of my (fail) attempts: First I try to look at 
$$\tag{3} Q_{1}X_1+Q_{2}X_3+\cdots+Q_{n}X_{2n-1}=0,\\
Q_{1}X_2+Q_{2}X_4+\cdots+Q_{n}X_{2n}=0$$
and conclude that $Q_i$ must be zero, which is wrong by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082386/fact-about-polynomials).

Next I try to prove it by induction on $n$. Setting $X_{2n-1}=X_{2n}=0$ in $(2)$, we can use the induction assumption to conclude that 
$$Q_{i,j}(X_1,X_2,...,X_{2n-3},X_{2n-2},0,0)=0\mbox{ for all }1\leq i\leq j\leq n-1.$$ Similarly, we can set $X_{2k-1}=X_{2k}=0$ in $(2)$ and by the induction assumption
we obtain
\begin{equation}
Q_{i,j}(X_1,...X_{2k-2},0,0,X_{2k+1},...,X_{2n})=0\mbox{ for }i\neq k\mbox{ or }j\neq k,
\end{equation}
where $k=1,2,..., n$.
Therefore, I try to look at $(3)$ with the extra condition that 
$$Q_i(x_1,...,\underbrace{0}_{(2j-1)-\mbox{th}},\underbrace{0}_{2j-\mbox{th}},...,x_{2n})=0\mbox{ for all }j\neq i.$$
and conclude that $Q_i$ must be zero, which is still wrong by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085619/another-fact-about-polynomials).

Comment: Hmmm if I understand correctly this is a system of $2n$ equations in $n(n+1)/2$ unknowns (over the field of rational functions of $X_i$).  So for $n\le 3$ it is probably true, but for $n>3$ it seems hopeless.